# How to validate in AWS serverless schema without plugin using only request

Tags: validation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to validate post request with body/payload and params:

```sh
curl -X POST \
  [url]/api/{param1}/comment/{param2} \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
        "bodyParam1": "45",
        "bodyParam2": 123123,
        "bodyParam3": 123
}
'
```

using the serverless framework for node js .

Here is my serverless.yml where I have tested with lambda and lambda-proxy and for both I couldn't validate params:

```
 functions:
  someName:
    handler: src/comment.post
    events:
      - http:
          integration: lambda-proxy
          path: /api/{param1}/comment/{param2}
          method: post
          request:
            schema:
              application/json: ${file(./src/models/schema1.json)}
          cors: true
```

And here is my schema1.json:

```js
{
  "definitions" : {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "title" :"Get object",
  "required": [
    "bodyParam1",
    "bodyParam2",
    "bodyParam3"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "bodyParam1":
    {
      "type":
      "string"
    },
    "bodyParam2":
    {
      "type":
      "integer"
    },
    "bodyParam3":
    {
      "type":
      "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this is native support of serverless request and not plugin version.

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `aws cli`:

```
aws cloudformation validate-template --template-body file://schema1.json
```

Comment: but don't you know the way to do this in serverless.yml without using aws cli?